# How do you remap :w to :w! and :q to :q! in my vimrc?

Tags: vim

I would like to always force write and force quit when using vim. Alternatively, if there's a mechanism to disable *all* warnings in vim, that would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply in `vimrc`:

```
map :w :w!
map :q :q!
```